# Is there online eBook authoring tool which can produce ePub and PDF formats?

Tags: editing, writing

I would prefer an online tool so that I am not tied to a particular computer for adding content. Additionally I would expect an online collaboration tool ( distribute chapters to authors and editors) to collaborate with other authors and editors. Exporting to ePub and PDF is a must have requirement.

Comment: May be something like this?
http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-epub

Comment: I search the same to write epub online, like a text processor, but online, and dedicated to books (jumping to the next chapters, etc...) with or without CSS support (showing and editing the code)

Answer (score 3):

I have heard of [2epub](http://www.2epub.com/) but I have never used it nor would I believe you would get a good quality ebook.  I would suggest doing this with InDesign that will allow you to create `.epub` or `.pdf` files.

You can export as an `.epub` file:

[image]

Export to `.pdf` file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) has live collaboration and is totally in the cloud. It can export PDF files and HTML files that can be easily converted to ePub.

This may also be possible with Microsoft Skydrive, but I am unfamiliar with that suite.

Comment: Collaboration okay, but to write epub, it's not particularly good.

Answer (score 1):

I am a founder at [memobuild](http://www.memobuild.com/), an online book/document editor with collaborative features and export to ePUB and PDF. It's oriented toward technical writing, so if you're writing a novel it's probably best to use something else. But for technical books, reports, manuals, etc... it's a great fit.

Note: We're currently in closed beta, but if you [register](http://www.memobuild.com/) I'll be happy to include you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Papyrus (http://papyruseditor.com) to create books in PDF, Epub and Mobi(Kindle) formats.

Disclosure : I am the creator of this site.

Answer (score 0):

[Mac OS Pages](http://www.apple.com/tr/mac/pages/) program File -> Export --> Epub...